# CSS child with position: fixed not respecting parent layout

Tags: css, css-position

If a positioned parent element (with `position: relative` or `position: absolute`) has a child element with `position: absolute`, then the child element will be positioned absolutely, within the positioned parent.

A child element with `position: sticky` behaves the same way - the child element will be positioned stickily, within the positioned parent.

But a child element with `position: fixed` will *not* take up a fixed position, within the positioned parent.

**Illustrative Example:**

```css
.panel {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 240px;
height: 180px;
margin-right: 6px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

header, footer {
display: block;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
width: 240px;
height: 24px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

header {
top: 0;
}

footer {
bottom: 0;
}

.panel + .panel header,
.panel + .panel footer {
position: sticky;
}

header code {
padding-left: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
<header><code>position: fixed</code></header>

<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, `and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice `without pictures or conversation?'</p>

<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>

<p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, `Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!' (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

<footer></footer>
</div>

<div class="panel">
<header><code>position: sticky</code></header>

<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, `and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice `without pictures or conversation?'</p>

<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>

<p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, `Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!' (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

<footer></footer>
</div>
```

Is javascript the only way around this?

Or is there a CSS approach which enables child elements with `position: fixed`, to take up a fixed position within their positioned parent element?

Comment: *I tell you, the children (with `position: fixed`) had respect for their parent (layouts) back in my day* ;)

Comment: If only. The truth is, these sort of children have never had any respect for their parents. I was wondering - in this new era of `position: sticky` - if the aforementioned children now had a new-found respect which they had previously lacked... but it seems not.

Comment: Damn millennials - we'll have to count on the next generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a javascript approach which enables the header and footer to adopt a *faux-fixed position* relative to the scrollable parent.

**Working Example:**

```js
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel')[0];
var panelHeader = panel.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
var panelFooter = panel.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];

function fixElements() {
    var panelHeight = panel.clientHeight;
    var panelFooterHeight = panelFooter.clientHeight;

    panelHeader.style.top = panel.scrollTop + 'px';
    panelFooter.style.top = panel.scrollTop + panelHeight - panelFooterHeight + 'px';
}

panel.addEventListener('scroll', fixElements, false);
```

```css
.panel {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 240px;
height: 180px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

header, footer {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 240px;
height: 24px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

header {
top: 0;
}

footer {
top: 156px;
}

header code {
padding-left: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.panel p:first-of-type {
padding-top: 12px;
}

.panel p:last-of-type {
padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
<header><code>position: faux-fixed</code></header>

<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, `and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice `without pictures or conversation?'</p>

<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>

<p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, `Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!' (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

<footer></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#fixed-pos), a fixed position is always relative to the viewport. So it's a feature.

Comment: Thank you. I knew this used to be the case but I was unaware that it still hadn't been updated. So... is there still no CSS approach to "fixing" a child element within a scrollable positioned parent element?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the parent style:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```